# Is it possible to put existing database into single user before running EF 6 migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there any way to put an existing database into single user mode before migrating it?

I would like to do something like the following, although this does not work:

```
        var connectionString = "";// Connection string pointing to MASTER database on server

        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();

        sqlConnection.Open();

        ExecuteNonQuery(
            sqlConnection,
            "USE MASTER");

        ExecuteNonQuery(
            sqlConnection,
            $"ALTER DATABASE [TargetDatabaseToMigrate] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF");

        ExecuteNonQuery(
            sqlConnection,
            $"ALTER DATABASE [TargetDatabaseToMigrate] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");

        TargetDatabaseContext ctx = new TargetDatabaseContext(sqlConnection, false);
        if(!ctx.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
        {
            var migrator = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TargetDatabaseContext, Migrations.Configuration>(true);
            migrator.InitializeDatabase(ctx);
        }

        ExecuteNonQuery(
            sqlConnection,
            $"ALTER DATABASE [TargetDatabaseToMigrate] SET MULTI_USER");

        ExecuteNonQuery(
            sqlConnection,
            $"ALTER DATABASE [TargetDatabaseToMigrate] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON");
```

I've looked through EF code and no code paths seem to use the existing connection passed in.  All code paths seem to use the connection information to create a new connection.

For example, this is where my code first fails while in EF:

```
   internal override void EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
    {
        var databaseCreated = false;
        var databaseCreator = new DatabaseCreator(_configuration.CommandTimeout);

        {
            DbConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = CreateConnection();
```

With the exception:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings.SqlProvider_CredentialsMissingForMasterConnection, e);
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?  Thank you.